# How to build boost with "Omit default library name" and Visual C++?

Tags: c++, boost

I try to build static Boost library that will not depend on project runtime version (MT or MD). The only thing required to build such library is to add `/Zl` option to command line.

I edited `tools/build/src/user-config.jam` and specify compiler flags here:

```
using msvc : : : <cxxflags>/Zl ;
```

When I open `rsp` files generates by boost build system, I see `/Zl` flag here, for example, in `regex.obj.rsp`:

```
"libs\regex\build\..\src\regex.cpp" -Fo"bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-14.1\release\address-model-64\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\regex.obj"    -TP /O2 /Ob2 /W4 /GR /MT /Zc:forScope /Zc:wchar_t /favor:blend /wd4675 /EHs /Zl -c 
-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 
-DNDEBUG 
"-I."
```

So, for me it looks like the resulted library can link both /MD and /MT. However, it is not true:

```
libboost_regex.lib(regex.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease'
```

This trick (with `/Zl`) works for me with `zlib`, `openssl`, `libcurl`, `libsqlite3` and many other libraries; can anyone explain why does it not work with `boost`? Does `boost` somehow override `/Zl` option even it exists in `rsp` file and in `user-config.jam`, or why `boost` libraries require the same version of runtime even `/Zl` option is supposed to make it runtime-independent?

Comment: I am not very certain at all, but I really thought that the /MD and /MT flags needed to match, even with a static library. I haven't used the libraries you listed off in awhile, but if I recall, at least a few of them weren't even libraries, but rather just amalgamated source you were to bring into your project. I often made them into dlls myself for use on my team.

That aside, Boost definitely has flags that tell it whether or not you are compiling static or dynamic libs. I think it was -D BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK. But the lack of it being defined should result in static libs.

Comment: Also, I think you can skip all of this mess by just adding boost via Nuget and be done with it. Not really any reason to compile it yourself anymore. You should be able to find a nuget package with what you want.